# Where to find the created articles in joomla 3.1 in the htdocs?

Tags: joomla3.1

I had a hard time of looking the created articles in joomla 3.1 in the htdocs where my joomla folder is found. Or is it possible for me to find the php code for my created article? Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

Your created articles are stored in the database, not as a script file. You should look at your #__content table.